# How To Use A Custom Router With Slim Framework 2?

Tags: php, slim

Trying to get a list of all routes loaded in Slim Framework. Need to know how to use a custom Router class which adds a method to get the protected `$routes` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can override `Slim\Slim` constructor and set the router that it will use, or you you can name all you routes and then you access the collection with the `Slim\Router::getNamedRoutes()` method.

```
<?php
$application->get(
    '/api',
    function () use ($application) {
        $routes = [];
        foreach ($application->router()->getNamedRoutes() as $route) {
            $routes[] = $route->getPattern();
        } 
        $application->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode([
            'total' => count($routes),
            'routes' => $routes
        ]);
    }
)->name('api');
```

Which will response with.

```
{
    total: 1,
    routes: [
        "/api"
    ]
}
```